# Unable to launch DART app from DART Editor on Windows

Tags: dart, dartium, dart-editor

I am on Windows 7 Home Premium. Subsequent runs in the DART Editor fail for me, I get the following message when running any of the web sample apps that come with the DART editor:

> java.io.IOException: Timed out trying to connect to Dartium
>   Timed out trying to connect to Dartium

The very first web app I run works, but after I close Dartium and re-run, this error persists. Please let me know if there are any workarounds.

Note: If I uncheck "Enable debugging" in my launch profile, then it will launch but it hangs at 75% during the launch (but the app runs). If "Enable debugging" is checked, then it hangs at 45% and loads a new Dartium instance at the standard landing page.

Answer (score 1):

I saw this issue documented [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.dart.general/15024). Here's an excerpt:

> Hey all, it looks like we did have an issue launching when extensions
>   were installed into Dartium. You can either update to the latest
>   continuous build to fix this, or work around the issue by disabling
>   extensions in Dartium/Chromium. The continuous builds can be found
>   here:
>   http://gsdview.appspot.com/dart-editor-archive-continuous/latest/.
>
> Devon Carew

I opted to get the latest build.